# Setting visibility of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to show my list view when the user clicks on a button and hide it again when they click on a button. This is the onClick listener for the button in question:

```
connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(open){
                mDbAdapter.close();
                connectBtn.setText("Open Database");
                open = false;
                hideUI();


            }else{
                mDbAdapter = new ContactsDbAdapter(v.getContext());
                mDbAdapter.open();
                connectBtn.setText("Close Database");
                open = true;
                showUI();
                //retrieve data
                fillData();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the showUI() method:

```
protected void showUI() {
    fName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fNameBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lNameBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    createBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    this.setVisible(true);

    createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDbAdapter.createContact(fNameBox.getText().toString(), lNameBox.getText().toString());
            fillData();
        }
    });
}
```

and the hideUI() method:

```
protected void hideUI() {
    fName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    lName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fNameBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fNameBox.clearComposingText();
    lNameBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    lNameBox.clearComposingText();
    createBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    this.setVisible(false);

}
```

It works fine when I set the visibility to true. However when I set it to false I get a black screen but no crash or error. Any idea?

NOTE: `this.setVisible(false);`. My class extends ListActivity.

Comment: i'd expect setVisible(false) on an activity to do just that. I don't understand your issue?

Comment: How can I hide a listView but keep the activity displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Just makes you view invisible but the space taken by view will be their itself

use `setVisibility(View.GONE);` so that the size of view will be lapsed

Use this and let me know if it is helpful

Comment: When I try this I am told that the method `setVisibility()`is undefined for the type MainActivity. I seem to be able to call this method on my other Views though.

Comment: ok then one option is left use get your list activity into a list object like list = getListView(); and then try to use setVisiblity method on that

Answer (score 0):

ListActivity is hold list view

if u do this.setVissiblity(false);
it hide the list view and its contents so u r seeing background color in ur case it is black.

Good way is take Listview in xml and get id make vissible nad invissible of that view u feel very confortable with this apprch

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html read this u will get clear idea. and make changes accordingly